# C++ istream (cin) and problem with waiting for a ENTER key press

Tags: c++, g++

Please, is there a way I can wait for a single <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press in all of the below cases? It works fine except when the `std::getline()` is used, which consumes the `\n`, and the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> needs to be pressed twice.

The code below works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

void waitForENTERKeyPress();

int main ()
{
    char c;
    string s;

    cout << "Enter c:"; cin >> c;
    waitForENTERKeyPress();

    cout << "Enter c:"; c = cin.get();
    waitForENTERKeyPress();

    cout << "Enter s:"; cin >> s;
    waitForENTERKeyPress();

    cout << "Enter s:"; std::getline(cin, s);
    waitForENTERKeyPress();

    return 0;
}

void waitForENTERKeyPress()
{
    // Does not work with std::getline(...)
    cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Press an ENTER to continue...\n";
    cin.get();    
}
```

====[UPDATE]============================================

Let me rephrase what I am looking for: The way how to make the `waitForENTERKeyPress()` function working in both cases – with `\n` in the buffer, when `cin` operator `>>` or `cin.get()` is used and also in cases the `std::getline()` is used.

From what I understand it is not possible as there is not a way how to detect if the `\n` is still in the buffer or not.
I have tried to use `cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()`, but it always returns `0`.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21567291/11082165)

Comment: >> This question already has answers here: Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction? NO IT HAS NOT. I know why it happens... I am asking how to solve it :(

Comment: I also disagree with the duplicate because this is the reverse.  @STeN, there is but one way: remove the unwanted line-ending after the operation that leaves the unwanted line ending, not before some future operation that may-or-may not have an unwanted line ending in the stream. `cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` will always ignore to the next line ending. If there is no line ending, it'll wait for one to be input.

Comment: Since `std::getline()` consumes the `\n`, simply DON'T call `waitForENTERKeyPress()` after it, since there is nothing to wait on. Same with `cin.get()` if it returns `\n`. That is not the case when using `operator>>`, hence the need to call `waitForENTERKeyPress()` after it.

Comment: To solve this, take `cin.ignore` statement out of the `waitForEnterKeyPress` function  , and call it when needed.  The function as it stands is poorly titled as it does two separate things:   remove a previous `\n`, and wait for enter key press.  Now that the situation arose where you need to do only one of those two things, you see why that was poor .

Comment: Thanks all for the comments - I was naively looking for such a variant of `waitForENTERKeyPress()` that will work in both cases – with `\n` in thr buffer (when `cin` operator `>>` or `cin.get()` is used and also in cases the `std::getline()` is used) – that seems not to be possible as there is not a way how to detect if the `\n` is still in the buffer or not. I have tried to use `cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()`, but it always returns 0.

Comment: It isn't clear what you expect the solution to do. Make `std::getline()` read a line up to but not including a newline character? It won't do that.